# using modified file content as arguments

Tags: bash, xargs, mercurial

In a script I'd like to purge a mercurial repository but be able to retain a number of (configurable) file patterns which I read from $FILENAME. The syntax for the hg command is

```
hg purge --all --exclude PATTERN1 --exclude PATTERN2 ...
```

Thus if $FILENAME contains a list of file patterns (one pattern per line), each pattern must be prepended by an "--exclude " in order to construct the command line

My current approach is to use for construction of the argument list
 
`grep -v -E "^[[:blank:]]*$" $FILENAME | sed "s/^/--exclude /g" | xargs echo`
which also will skip empty lines and those which only contain tabs or spaces which would result in an error if used to construct the above command line. Thus in total:

```
hg purge --all `grep -v -E "^[[:blank:]]*$" $FILENAME | sed "s/^/--exclude /g" | xargs echo`
```

Is there a nicer way, maybe with some xargs arguments which I'm unaware of?

Comment: What does `$FILENAME` look like? Is it one pattern per line?

Comment: @terdon one file name per line

Comment: simpler way : `grep -v -E "^[[:blank:]]*$" $FILENAME | sed "s/^/--exclude /g" | xargs hg purge --all `

Comment: @terdon: yes indeed, my idea is to require one pattern per line in $FILENAME. I amended my question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems there is even a shorthand way in mercurial itself, making use of file lists (suggested by mg in #mercurial):
`hg purge --all --exclude "listfile:$FILENAME"`

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you're using `grep` and `xargs` at all. Given a file of patterns like this:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

You could run

```
$ echo hg purge --all $(perl -pe 's/^/--exclude /' file)
hg purge --all --exclude foo --exclude bar --exclude baz
```

Or even

```
$ echo hg purge --all $(sed 's/^/--exclude /' file)
hg purge --all --exclude foo --exclude bar --exclude baz
```

Just remove the `echo` to actually run the commands.

Comment: Ah, that's indeed much nicer than my solution above. Thanks :)

Comment: @planetmaker you're welcome :). For future reference, the way to express thanks on the SE network of sites is to upvote answers you find useful and eventually [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one that solves your issue.

Comment: @planetmaker For reference, saying thanks is also fine.:-) In general people appreciate it. Also upvote as appropriate, of course.